# What day is today?

Tags: riddle, seasonal

In The True North,

something, a special something,

big and red, swaying in the wind.

held up by a pole, like the leaf

commonly found in the area.

And today is it's day.

> Hint: what sauce do you put on pancakes?

What is the "something" mentioned in the poem?
What is this leaf?
And what holiday is today?

> Note: I'm bad at rhyming, so sorry about that.

> Note 2: The riddle may not be accurate about what day it is, but you can check the date when this question was created to know what day the poem is talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the only thing not yet explicitly mentioned,

> Something == Canada flag, since it's held by a pole, and there's a reference to a maple tree.

> but the day is still Canada day. Not quite sure, should there be several answers, but don't seem to find the fitting single answer for questions asked.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the "something" is

> Canada.

- Therefore perhaps the 'holiday' celebrated would be

> July First - Canada's independence day, which is TODAY - at the time I'm posting this answer.

> "In the True North" - since Canada is in the north (and - I believe, parts of it are in the Arctic Circle)

> "big and red, swaying in the wind. held up by a pole, like the leaf commonly found in the area." - This refers to Canada's flag, which center is a red maple tree leaf - [image]

> "And today is it's day." - Today - at least at the time this question was asked and at the time I'm posting this answer, is July First, Canada's independence day.

> I still have yet to find out how the hint relates though...

Comment: not exactly, it says that in the true north, not the true north. But you are very close.

Comment: @python_coder I see you have suggested an edit. However, this is not the correct way to do it. The better way would be to comment on my post, explaining the hint.

Comment: The hint refers to rot13(Zncyr flehc, gur zncyr orvat Pnanqn'f rzoyrz)

Comment: Vg vf abg Vaqrcraqrapr Qnl. Vg vf gur Angvbany Qnl. uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Pnanqn_Qnl